# Where can I find local deployed war by tomcat?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, intellij-idea

I use tomcat 7 via Intellij IDEA 13. Tomcat home is `/usr/share/tomcat7`, tomcat base is `/var/lib/tomcat7`. `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` contains single folder `ROOT` where I can find initial tomcat webapp with different instructions.

So where can I find my local deployed webapp? or where is the server root folder?

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` is the place where you should find your local deployed app, right next to the ROOT folder you see.
If it is not there, then there might be some problem in your deployment.
Are you sure you have deployed it correctly?

Comment: I'm sure, because I don't do it manually, this process is handled by IDEA, and the app is accessible in browser.

Comment: In that case, I think your app is being deployed to any built in server within IDEA. Can you confirm that IDEA does not have any built in web server?

Comment: I define server to use in run configuration of IDEA.

Comment: I think that is the case. I am not sure about IDEA, you should find the web server folder within the installation folder of IDEA.

Comment: I define server by specifying paths to tomcat home and tomcat base folders i.e. `/usr/share/tomcat7` and `/var/lib/tomcat7/`